# Workaround for lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of the inactive member of a union within relaxed constant expressions

Tags: c++, unions, c++14, constexpr

Triggering lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of the inactive member of a union is not a constant expression. That is, given the `union`:

```
template<class T, class U>
union A {
  constexpr A(T t) : t_{t} {}
  constexpr A(U u) : u_{u} {}
  T t_;
  U u_;
};
```

and the `constexpr` function `foo`:

```
template<class T, class U>
constexpr auto foo() {
  A<T, U> a(T{});
  return a.u_;
}
```

the following program:

```
int main() {
  constexpr auto test = foo<int, double>();
  return 0;
}
```

fails with the error message:

```
error: constexpr variable 'test' must be initialized by a
      constant expression
  constexpr auto test = foo<int, double>();
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: read of member 'u_' of union with active member 't_' is
      not allowed in a constant expression
  return a.u_;
         ^
note: in call to 'foo()'
  constexpr auto test = foo<int, double>();
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a workaround to achieve this behavior within constant expressions in C++14? `reinterpret_cast` isn't allowed either.

Motivation: I'm trying to make google-test's floating-point comparison utility constexpr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do type punning in constant expressions in C++14. There's no way to do it outside of constant expressions either; the code you showed will have undefined behavior at runtime.

As an example of why this is disallowed in general, consider this:

```
union U { int *p; size_t n; };
int a;
constexpr U u = { &a };
static_assert(u.n != 0x400e158, "'a' is at my favourite address");
```

If this were allowed, an implementation would be required to determine the runtime address of `a` during compilation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Richard. In the Google Test framework there is a class for performing floating point comparison that it is widely used (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423299/1422197). It uses a union to store a floating point number, and switch to its bit representation. Is it also invoking undefined behavior? One could do a `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>` instead, would that be also invoking undefined behavior?

Comment: I can see in your example why this is disallowed in general within constant expressions. But then in the example one is taking the address of a runtime variable. In the code I showed the objective is to view a `constexpr` variable of some type, as if it were a constexpr variable of a different type (something like reinterpret cast could also do, but it would probably be undefined behavior too).

Comment: Yes, that code has undefined behavior. Note that GCC has an extension [documented here] (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#nonbugs_c) that allows such type punning through unions in some cases. `reinterpret_cast<unsigned>(my_float)` is ill-formed; that's not a conversion that can be performed by `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I see, i'll try to figure out an alternative way without invoking UB. Thanks a lot for the clarifications!

Comment: could I memcopy the float (or double) into a sufficiently large unsigned integer type to get rid of the undefined behavior here?

Comment: Yes, you could, but not within a constant expression (`memcpy` is not `constexpr`).

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep trying.